# I had this problem to connect me to the main activity: Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function'

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this problem to connect the menu to the main activity:

**Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function'**

This is the main activity code:

```
enter code heclass MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var adapter: Adapter
private lateinit var layoutManger:LinearLayoutManager 

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    layoutManger = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    adapter = Adapter()
    val list = ArrayList<Model>()
    list.apply {
        add(Model("fatemeh", "chamani fard"))
        add(Model("reyhaneh", "chamani fard"))
        add(Model("bahareh", "chamani fard"))
        add(Model("abolfazl", "chamani fard"))
    }

    adapter.setList(list)
    list_main.layoutManager=layoutManger
    list_main.adapter=adapter
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

}
```

}re

It gives an error on the word OVERRIDE

AND code menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuItemNew"
    android:icon="@drawable/icons8_add_100"
    android:title="new"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuItemSearch"
    android:icon="@drawable/icons8_search_150"
    android:title="search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

error:
**Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function'**

Help me please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are creating your `onCreateOptionsMenu` function inside your `onCreate` making it a local function.

Make sure your `onCreateOptionsMenu` function is inside the class instead.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var adapter: Adapter
    private lateinit var layoutManger:LinearLayoutManager 

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    layoutManger = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    adapter = Adapter()
    val list = ArrayList<Model>()
    list.apply {
        add(Model("fatemeh", "chamani fard"))
        add(Model("reyhaneh", "chamani fard"))
        add(Model("bahareh", "chamani fard"))
        add(Model("abolfazl", "chamani fard"))
    }

    adapter.setList(list)
    list_main.layoutManager=layoutManger
    list_main.adapter=adapter
}


 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
 }
}
```